# jsx style with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know I can do condition with **className** but how about style?

```
<span style={{float:'right'}}>Something</span>
```

Like for above jsx, I want to float right if `obj.name` is equal to `'active'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to CSS display:none within conditional with React JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728951/how-to-css-displaynone-within-conditional-with-react-jsx)

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to set this in the **render** method of the component. I personally think that this is a more readable solution overall:

```
render() {
    let customStyles = obj.name === 'active' ? { float: 'right' } : {};
    return (<span style={customStyles}>Something</span>);
}
```

You'll need to have `obj` in scope for this to work of course.

Answer (score 1):

One Way, if you want the whole `style` only when the `object.name == 'active'`:

```
<span style={obj.name == 'active' ? {float:'right'} : {}}>Something</span>
```

Another, when you want to put the condition on separate `style property` values:

```
<span style={{float: obj.name == 'active' ? 'right' : ''}}>Something</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below mentioned Pattern.

```
reder(){
return(
let myStyle = {float:right; marginBottom:10;} //in JSX/JS hyphen sign is replaced with Camel case notation, it will automatically detected by ReactDOM renderer.
<span style={myStyle}></span>
);
}
```

for specifying any condition:

```
reder(){
return(
let myStyle = (obj.name == "active") ? {float:right; marginBottom:10;} : {};
<span style={myStyle}></span>
);
}
```